# Effects of slightly lower gravity?

Tags: gravity

If a planet were to have a gravitational acceleration of .7g, how different would it be from walking on earth, assuming this is not someone born outside of earth. Would it be a slight bounce in your step or more noticeable than that?

Sorry if this has been asked, I couldn't find anything when searching, just about super low or no gravity.

Comment: You can experiment it yourself. Find a building with a fast elevator. 0.7~0.8g is what you feel when you go up and it starts decellerating.

Comment: Hmm... The person has already left. But the moon is not 0.6 gravity but 0.166 gravity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what happens when you walk: there is one horizontal frictional compnent, and another vertical Normal component to the walk.

[image]

When the gravity goes from `g` -> `0.7 g`, this is going to effect on the counterbalancing of `N`, the Normal component. However, there will not be any effect on the frictional component (assuming point landing).

So you will see a distinct hop in the walk (as you will go little higher than usual).

Comment: Thumbs up for that drawing. :^)

Answer (score 6):

**Definitely noticable, but not "I have superpowers".**

Basically, it'd have the same effect as someone who was pretty overweight going on a heck of a diet. I'm 6'2 and 240lbs on Earth right now, on your world I'd feel like I weighed 170, which was about thirty years ago for me. So yeah, pretty noticeable, and older people would notice the difference a lot more since it wouldn't just be "Hey, I'm feeling stronger", it'd be "Wow, all this stuff doesn't HURT anymore."

Comment: Or more easily achievable (since diets are slow enough that you adapt to the weight change): go backpacking for a couple of weeks with a pack that's ~30% of your body weight, then notice how you walk the first day you're home.